# Curvature in Minkowski space?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, curvature, equivalence-principle

Lately am thinking of how the equivalence principle has made up GR and how can I represent it as elementary as possible in my head.

So the idea that had Einstein back then was that given an inertial frame associated with a freely falling test particle (the test particle experience no gravitational pull whatsoever) in a homogeneous gravitational field,  we can do a change of basis to a non-inertial one so that the particle will experience a gravitational pull, but the thing is that this test particle lives in a Minkowski space where the curvature is null due to the fact that the particle described in the non-inertial frame is not feeling it's weight. In addition, the Christoffel symbols do exist in a Minkowski space but the curvature is zero, in consequence, the gravitational field is fictitious.

So we get to the last part, what I've understood and what you need to confirm for me is that when we activate a real gravitational field we pass to a Riemannian space and apply the equivalence principle where space-time is locally like Minkowski space.

Edited: The main goal here is to see if what am saying is correct, thus I will try to be more clear and formal.

Let's suppose a test particle living in a Minkowski space $(M_4,\eta)$ where the curvature $R^\rho{}_{\lambda \mu \nu}=0$ but the connexion is not necessarily $\Gamma = 0$, In other words, this test particle is in a homogeneous gravitational field(HGF). we assign to this particle an inertial frame $(\mathbf{e}_0,\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2,\mathbf{e}_3)$ the latter gives us the equation of motion $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}t^2}=0$$
If we pass to another non-inertial frame $(\mathbf{e'}_0,\mathbf{e'}_1,\mathbf{e'}_2,\mathbf{e'}_3)$ we get
$$ \frac{dx'^\mu}{dt}+ \tilde{\Gamma}_{\ \nu \lambda}^{\mu}\frac{dx'^{\nu}}{dt} \frac{dx'^{\lambda}}{dt}=0  $$
Where $\tilde{\Gamma}_{\ \nu \lambda}^{\mu}$ are the Christoffel symbols, what we can see is that in a Minkowski space we can change basis and find that there is a connection that appears which means gravity is in place (but in fact it's a fictitious one) this non-inertial frame describes the motion of a freely falling particle.

So what we can see is that when we change coordinates in Minkowski space we find that a connection appears but a curvature stills zero. This means that when we really want to activate gravity i.e. passing to general relativity, we need to pass to a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with a non-zero Riemann curvature tensor.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking here. In particular, I don't know what you mean by the curvature being null *due to the fact that the particle described[...] is not feeling its weight*, nor do I really understand the last paragraph (though GR regards spacetime as a *Lorentzian*, not Riemannian, manifold).

Comment: The point of GR is to not require spacetime to be MInkowski, just to have its $+---$ (or $-+++$, depending in your convention) signature. The more general options have curvature that give us gravity.

Comment: I’m voting to close because this doesn't appear to be a question.

Comment: @PaulT. it's an observation mainly and the question is: Tell me if am right or wrong to think all of that. I've said it in the last paragraph

Comment: @J.G. oh yes, but in my post it's not really about general relativity it's about the experience of Einstein and the Minkowski space having a fictitious gravitational field expressed by the Christoffel symbols and a Curvature $R=0$ when we pass to a non-inertial frame.

Comment: @intelligibleno In that case, the following observation may help: while the Ricci scalar $R$ can be $0$ for some curved spacetimes, the Riemann tensor $R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ has all components $0$ in either all or no coordinate systems. For example, the Schwarzschild metric has $R=0$ but non-vanishing Riemann tensor.

Comment: @J.G. thank you for this observation, which I have already encountered in a lecture. Oh by $R=0$ I don't mean the Ricci scalar but the Riemann.

Comment: @intelligibleno Then your proposal doesn't work: if the Riemann tensor vanished, we wouldn't observe evidence of it being nonzero, such as Schwarzschild-like gravitation.

Comment: @J.G. I can argue by saying that when we consider Minkowski space and the equation of motion in a non-inertial frame as cited above we can clearly see that a non-inertial frame give rise to a fictitious gravitational field that we can represent by $\Gamma$ .

Comment: @intelligibleno I suspect you're conflating "I can turn this into that in a local patch with a suitable patch-specific coordinate  transformation" with "I can turn this into that globally with the result of one coordinate transformation".

Comment: Let me suggest an edit to your second-to-last paragraph (the one immediately before "Is my reasoning good?"), and you tell me if you agree with my edit. My changes are in **bold.** "So what we can see is that when we change **coordinates** in **Minkowski spacetime** we find that a connection appears but a curvature stills zero. This means that when we really want to activate gravity i.e. passing to general relativity, we need to pass to a manifold $(M,g)$ **with a non-zero Riemann curvature tensor**."

Comment: @Andrew yes why not it's pretty much the same idea but a little bit clearer.

Comment: Well... it's not the same thing. "Frame" vs "coordinate" is basically a preference. But a "Lorentz manifold" is one where the metric has eigenvalues $-1, 1, 1, 1$ (or $1, -1, -1, -1$ if you use the wrong conventions :)), and in particular spacetimes with non-zero Riemann curvature still are Lorentzian manifolds. Also a "Riemannian manifold" has a metric with eigenvalues $+1, +1, +1, +1$, so no spacetime is a Riemannian manfiold, even Minkowski space. I agree with your statement if you mean something equivalent to my edit, but I think the comments you got were due to using language imprecisely.

Comment: @Andrew Oh yes I should use pseudo-Riemannian manifold instead of "Riemannian manifold" you are totally right and for the Lorentzian manifold you have a good point I was confusing a Lorentzian Manifold with Minkowski space thank you for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are mostly correct in your thinking. However, it looks like you are (at least partly) associating gravity with non-vanishing Christoffel symbols, which may be worth commenting on.

Gravity is associated with the curvature of spacetime, and since spacetime is curved according to its energy content, we sometimes say that in empty (i.e. Minkowski) spacetime there is no gravity.

Now, a lot of the mathematical framework of differential geometry is usually associated with general relativity (rather than special relativity). However, things like Christoffel symbols, geodesic equations, covariant derivatives are actually not specific to GR, they can appear in SR as well. The new thing in GR is the non-vanishing curvature tensor (which in SR is always zero).

The reason why people usually learn about things like Christoffel symbols or covariant derivatives only when studying GR is because you can do all of SR in inertial coordinates where the connection coefficients vanish and the covariant derivatives are the usual partial derivatives. But if you were to study SR in arbitrary coordinate systems, you would encounter all of these objects (except the curvature tensor) while still doing SR.

In summary, the point is that the way this material is though is usually as follows: special relativity in inertial coordinates (in which one never meets the Christoffel symbols or covariant derivatives) then general relativity (where one meets the Christoffel symbols, covariant derivatives, curvature tensor, etc.). This way of teaching may make one think all of these objects are specific to GR (and hence make them associate them with gravity).

However, one can also learn this material as follows: special relativity in inertial coordinates, then special relativity in arbitrary coordinates (where one meets things like Christoffel symbols and covariant derivatives), then general relativity (where the curvature tensor appears). This makes it clearer that it is only the curvature tensor that is specific to GR, not the Christoffel symbols and covariant derivatives.

Comment: A good thing of seeing this is writing down a flat Minkowski metric in e.g. spherical coordinates. One can then easily compute non-vanishing Christoffel symbols. The curvature tensor, however, vanishes. The Christoffel symbols contain information on both curvature and curvilinear coordinates. Combining them into the curvature tensor isolates the former.

Comment: I totally follow your point and I want to make a remark: I called the Christoffel symbols a fictitious gravitational field because of the fact we are in a non-inertial reference frame and the motion will be described in Newtonian mechanics by a fictitious force.

Comment: Yes, I kind of realized this is what you were saying. I tried to avoid, however, calling the Christoffel symbols a fictitious gravitational field because I am not sure this is standard terminology.